# cassandraunit unable to start EmbeddedCassandraServer

Tags: unit-testing, spring-boot, cassandra

I want to unit test my `cassandra service` so found `cassandra-unit` is the one i can use. SO I am using `cassandra-unit:3.1.1.0` to unit test my `cassandraservice` followed a sample project found [Here](https://github.com/jsevellec/cassandra-unit-examples) but I am not able to run an `embedded cassandra` server to run my unit tests. Please let me know what is wrong or is there any other library available to test the cassandra.

#### My Test Class

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TestExecutionListeners({ CassandraUnitTestExecutionListener.class })
@CassandraDataSet(value = { "simple.cql" })
@EmbeddedCassandra(configuration = "cassandra.yml")
public class CassandraServiceTest {

    @Test
    public void should_execute_batch() throws Exception {
        ResultSetFuture result = session.executeAsync(batch);
        assertNotNull(result);
    }
}
```

#### Got timeout error -

I am always getting time out error, not sure how to increase the timeout interval for `EmbeddedServer`

```
16:14:13.056 [main] ERROR org.cassandraunit.utils.EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper - Cassandra daemon did not start after 10000 ms. Consider increasing the timeout
16:14:13.067 [main] WARN org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.cassandraunit.spring.CassandraUnitTestExecutionListener@704921a5] to process 'before' execution of test method [public void CassandraServiceTest.should_execute_batch() throws java.lang.Exception] for test instance [CassandraServiceTest@45a37759]
java.lang.AssertionError: Cassandra daemon did not start within timeout
```

#### Dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
    <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
    <artifactId>cassandra-driver-mapping</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.cassandraunit</groupId>
    <artifactId>cassandra-unit-spring</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.cassandraunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-unit</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.cassandraunit</groupId>
    <artifactId>cassandra-unit</artifactId>
    <classifier>shaded</classifier>
    <version>3.1.1.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hectorclient</groupId>
    <artifactId>hector-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at this thread:
https://github.com/jsevellec/cassandra-unit/issues/128

Basically you should increase the timeout:
https://github.com/jsevellec/cassandra-unit/pull/127

In your @EmbeddedCassandra annotation with config file you can also set the timeout.

Comment: thank you. I still unable to run the `embedded server` even after increasing timeout to `150000L`